# 'pip install kaggle' works fine - but 'kg command not found'

Tags: pip, ubuntu-16.04, kaggle

I installed kaggle-cli just fine.. everything went smoothly or so pip says.

But when I try to run the `kg` command or just `kg --version`, I get

> kg command not found

I can see Kaggle in Python system packages and all the `py` and `pyc` files are there. But like no `bin` directory or anything.

I tried to find a similar issue online with no success - so I thought I would try here.

I am on an Ubuntu app for Windows 10. Everything else in terms of Python, [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras), [Theano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theano_(software)), etc. for my machine learning rig works just fine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shortly after you asked this question, Kaggle released an official API which I recommend you use in place of [kaggle-cli](https://github.com/floydwch/kaggle-cli). `pip install kaggle` will install the official API which supports these commands:

> `kaggle competitions {list, files, download, submit, submissions}`
>
> `kaggle datasets {list, files, download, create, version, init}`
>
> `kaggle config {view, set, unset}`

Check out the [documentation here](https://github.com/kaggle/kaggle-api). After installing, you will also need to generate an API token from your Kaggle user profile "Account" tab.

Answer (score 15):

The same problem for me. Kaggle is correctly installed with `pip install kaggle --user`, but *"kaggle command was not found"*.

I located the Kaggle executable in `~/.local/bin/kaggle` and solved it creating a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`:

```
ln -s ~/.local/bin/kaggle /usr/bin/kaggle
```

Comment: Does not work for me, for some autorisation reason: even with `sudo` I have this message :
`ln: /usr/bin/kaggle: Operation not permitted`

Comment: It partially worked for me. Not I get an error: Could not find kaggle.json.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on the GCP. 
What I did was to reinstall it again as with the

```
pip install kaggle --user
```

Then added the directory (shown in the warning after the installation) to the [PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)
Then I just reopened the remote access window.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the API using `pip install kaggle` might still not resolve the issue. You would have to add kaggle to PATH. Opening ~/.bashrc and adding `alias kaggle="~/.local/bin/kaggle"` to the end of the file worked for me.